# I want to use integration for performing summation in Algebra

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, summation

I am a class 9th student. Sorry if my problem is silly.

I am trying to find the sum of squares from 1 to 10. For this I tried summation, and it was fine.
But now I came to know that Integration can be also used for summation.

But the problem is I am not able to get correct answer. The sum of squares from 1 to 10 is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{10} n^2 = 385$$ but after doing integration answer is
$$\int_1^{10} x^2 \, dx= \left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_1^{10} = 333$$ which is quite less than the actual answer.

What is the correct way of calculating squares from 1 to 10 via integration? Am I mistaken something?

Comment: Do you similarly think the area of a triangle with a particular base and height is the same as the area of a rectangle with that same base and height?  Same error.

Answer (score 2):

Using integration as a substitute for the summation is an interesting but problematic idea.

Your integration captures the area under the curve of the continuous function $~f(x)=x^2,~$ as opposed to the area under the step function :  $~g(x)~$   defined by

- $g(x)=1 ~: ~1 \leq x < 2$
- $g(x)=4 ~: ~2 \leq x < 3$
- $\cdots$
- $g(x)=100 ~: ~10 \leq x < 11$

As a separate issue, your integration specifies an interval of [1,10].  Analogizing the summation to the area under the step function $~g(x),~$ this overlooks the area under the interval [10,11].

As expected, if you instead change the integration to $~\displaystyle \int_1^{11} x^2 ~dx ~$ then you get $~\displaystyle \left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_1^{11} > 385.~$  That is, with the intervals aligned, you would expect the area under the continuous function to be greater than the area under the step function.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to making *asymptotic* estimates, integration and summation behave in similar (not equal, but similar) ways when looking at their growth rate, when they diverge. As an example, when $k$ is a nonnegative integer,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N n^k \sim \int_1^N x^k\,dx = \frac{N^{k+1}}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+1} \sim \frac{N^{k+1}}{k+1}
$$
when $N \to \infty$

To compare a sum and related integral when you have concrete bounds (not variable upper bounds), look up the Euler Maclaurin summation formula.

Answer (score 0):

As @KCd suggested, Euler-McLaurin summation is very interesting to use for this kind of problem.

For your case,
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p  {n^2}$$
depending on the level of expansion, you would obtain
$$S_p=\frac{p^3}{3}+\frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{p}{6}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$ which gives the exact result.

If you do the same for
$$T_p=\sum_{n=1}^p  {n^k}$$ it would give
$$T_p =\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{2} \left(p^k+1\right)$$ Notice that making $k=2$, you would obtain $383.5$ which is not exact.

Use it for $k=\pi$ and $p=20$. The approximate result would be $65156.6$ while the exact value is $65316.4$ (relative error of $0.25$%).